# Does MVVMCross use tcp to have remote views

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm new to MVVMCross and I'm trying to see if it does remote views over tcp. From the docs I have read, it looks like the only remote part would be the database (eg MSSQL over TCP) but that seems all wrong.

Does MVVMCross have a communications layer between the ModelView and the Model ? If so, is there any documentation on it. I have looked but have not found any.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have most of the application on one machine and have a thin client (ie the View) able to run remotly. The only information I have found on this is that it seems to be done for mobile devices but I have not been able to find any details on the communications interface.

Comment: mmm I'm not sure if I follow. Do you want to have a mobile app that displays something that is processed elsewhere?
Why don't you make an app and connect it to the server using an `HttpClient`? So you get the data and display in the mobile device as you want.
If what you want is something else please explain a little more and I'll try to help

Comment: I'm trying to determine if MVVMCross allows the Model to be on a server and the View to be on a client. Is it able to perform the TCP communications between the Model and the View managing the transfer of the ViewModel data between the 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it doesn't. You should communicate with your server through `HttpClient` or if you want something more real time you can use something like `SignalR` to get your model and update the `Viewmodel` which will end up updating the `View`.

If you want an example of either approaches tell me.

HIH.